# What's difference between `Dism /Capture-Image` and `recimg -CreateImage` on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, wmi, refresh, wim

I'm trying to make sense of wimboot vs refresh. Can someone give a short answer to the following?

What's the difference between 
`Dism /Capture-Image`
and 
`recimg -CreateImage`

They both produce .wim files. What's the difference between the wim files they produce?

Thx

Comment: "that specific installation. If you want an image that can be applied to any partition..." -- hearing apples to oranges again. Asking if the refresh image can be applied to another PC refresh process, not "another partition".

Comment: "Recovery image is used to Refresh the installation, the created .wim image, is used to apply to a partition which would wipe any data on the partition" --Recovery image wipes the partition?

Comment: Either you, or Microsoft, are mixing terms "recovery" and "refresh". I thought "Refresh" only restores the OS, without wiping the partition. But your comment above says Refresh wipes the partition.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between the wim files they produce?

If you type `recimg /?` in a command prompt it would display the following information.

> C:>recimg /?
>
> Configures the recovery image Windows uses to refresh your PC.
>
> RECIMG.EXE
>
> The recimg.exe command line tool lets you configure a custom recovery
>   image for Windows to use when you refresh your PC. When you create a
>   custom recovery image, it will contain the desktop apps you've
>   installed, and the Windows system files in their current state.
>   Recovery images do not contain your documents, personal settings, user
>   profiles, or apps from Windows Store, because that information is
>   preserved at the time you refresh your PC.
>
> When you create a custom recovery image, recimg will store it in the
>   specified directory, and set it as the active recovery image. If a
>   custom recovery image is set as the active recovery image, Windows
>   will use it when you refresh your PC. You can use the /setcurrent and
>   /deregister options to select which recovery image Windows will use.
>   All recovery images have the filename CustomRefresh.wim. If no
>   CustomRefresh.wim file is found in the active recovery image
>   directory, Windows will fall back to the default image (or to
>   installation media) when you refresh your PC.
>
> Note that you cannot reset your PC using a custom recovery image.
>   Custom recovery images can only be used to refresh your PC.

This means `recimg -CreateImage` is used to create that image used by the recovery environment to **Refresh** the Windows installation in question.

Source: [Why and when "recimg" is canceled in Windows 10?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_repair/why-and-when-recimg-is-canceled-in-windows-10/1193d4b3-8729-40cc-a3ce-702c676820e8)

/Capture-Image simply does the following:

> Capture images for each customized partition.

`/Capture-Image` can be used to create an image of a storage device's existing partition.  This would be typically be used, to create multiple .wim images of a system's partitions, in order to deploy it to other machines on a network so they are identical.

Source: [Capture Images of Hard Disk Partitions Using DISM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825072.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Also, what's the difference between a .wmi file and a .wim file.

.WMI is a [Windows Management Instrumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) script file.  It has nothing to do with either command.

Answer (score 0):

**`Dism /Capture-Image`** captures one or more entire partitions. It's used for creation of custom Windows installation media, unattended Windows installs, simple partition-image-and-restore, and WimBoot setups. When applied to a partition, it will overwrite the entire partition.

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825131.aspx#bkmk_3
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825072.aspx
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824910.aspx
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn594399.aspx

**`recimg -CreateImage`** captures installed OS and application files only. It's used for the Windows Refresh procedure. When applied to a partition, it will *not* overwrite the entire partition.

The `wim` extension indicates the compression-type of the file.

Comment: 1) If you manually apply the created .wim file to a partition, it would indeed, overwrite your data on that partition.  2) Windows Recovery has nothing to do with /Create-Image, that's the recimg, which stands for recovery image.  When any .wim is applied to a partition your replacing the data on the partition, but the recovery image you create, isn't applied but used to Refresh your Windows installation.  Correct your inaccurate statements and I will just delete my answer.

Comment: @Ramhound, ok, i'm but currently researching difference between "System Refresh" and "System Image Restore", and which of these 2 wim's is used for which. Also trying to see if "System Image Backup" GUI is equivalent to DISM.

Comment: from your comment, it sounds like there's only 1 inaccurate statement, which i fixed by changing "Windows Recovery" to  "System Image Restore". Right?

Comment: No; [System Image Restore](https://www.howtogeek.com/167984/how-to-create-and-restore-system-image-backups-on-windows-8.1/) is something else entirely

Comment: "System Image Backup" and "System Image Restore" makes an iso or recovery media, not wim?

Comment: You tell me; This is your answer, I just saw an inaccurate statements. The .wim image created by /Capture-Image isn't used by system image recovery, which is file history, and doesn't use a .wim image at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57665/discussion-between-johny-why-and-ramhound).